# jQuery how to get string after last symbol

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following string:

```
<div class="main_menu_link" data-ajax-url="http://mytestdomain.com/temp-param-page-2/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=720960&wpv_post_search&wpv-men-bags%5B0%5D=clutches"></div>

http://mytestdomain.com/temp-param-page-2/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=720960&wpv_post_search&wpv-men-bags%5B0%5D=clutches
```

I need to get all of the text e.g. `clutches` after the last `=` symbol.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str=$('.main_menu_link').data('ajax-url');
str.split("=").pop()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3p0h2z3k/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = $('.main_menu_link').data('ajax-url');
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
```